# Dropping some columns when using to_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which I want to write to tow files, one that contains all of the columns and one that has only a subset of the columns 
So for this data frame:

```
 Out_data
 Out[9]: 
    A     B                 C          D       E         F
0  354   49985400          10          07   7.140899  0.212044
1  738   49985400          10          07   7.140899  0.212044
2  738   49985277          11          09   4.024423  0.098387
3  246   49985279          10          07   7.140899  0.212044
```

I want to have it exported to two csv files, one that has all the data, and the second one that has only data from columns A,B, C and D, so that the csv would look like this:

```
  A,B,C,D,E,F
354,49985400,10,07,7.140899,0.212044
738,49985400,10,07,7.140899,0.212044
738,49985277,11,09,4.024423,0.098387
246,49985279,10,07,7.140899,0.212044
```

And the second one will look like:

```
  A,B,C,D
354,49985400,10,07
738,49985400,10,07
738,49985277,11,09
246,49985279,10,07
```

I am able to get the first file using:

```
Out_data.to_csv(filename, mode = 'w', index=False)
```

I tried using

```
Out_data.to_csv(filename, mode = 'w', cols = ['A','B','C','D'] ,index=False)
```

But I still go the exact same output file? 
How can I get to_csv to export but drop some of the columns?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be using `columns` as the keyword argument, not `cols`.

```
Out_data.to_csv(filename, mode='w', columns=['A','B','C','D'], index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
Out_data[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].to_csv(filename, mode = 'w' ,index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but the solution suggested by root runs faster with the data I have.

Answer (score 4):

Create a set "columns_to_exclude" and a set that contains names of "all_columns"

```
columns_to_exclude = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
all_columns = set(data_frame.keys())

data_frame.to_csv('file_name.csv', columns=list(columns_to_exclude.symmetric_difference(all_columns)))
```

Comment: I like your solution. I feel it's more readable. I would propose `all_columns - columns_to_exclude` as opposed to `columns_to_exclude.symmetric_difference(all_columns)` given columns_to_exclude should be a subset of all_columns.