# How to drop a specific column of csv file while reading it using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I need to remove a **column** with label **name** at the time of loading a csv using `pandas`. I am reading csv as follows and want to add parameters inside it to do so. Thanks.

`pd.read_csv("sample.csv")`

I know this to do after reading csv:

```
df.drop('name', axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you know in advance what columns your CSV has?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I don't know the total number of columns but it will be more than 100. I need the code to work for any number of columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you know the column names prior, you can do it by setting `usecols` parameter

**When you know which columns to use**

Suppose you have csv file with columns `["id", "name", "last_name"]` and you want just `["name", "last_name"]`. You can do it as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", usecols=["name", "last_name"])
```

**when you want first N columns**

If you don't know the column names but you want first N columns from dataframe. You can do it by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", usecols=[i for i in range(n)])
```

**Edit**

**When you know name of the column to be dropped**

```
# Read column names from file
cols = list(pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv", nrows=1))
print(cols)

# Use list comprehension to remove the unwanted column in **usecol**
df= pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv", usecols =[i for i in cols if i != "name"])
```

Comment: I need every other columns except the column labeled '**name**' and i dont know other labels, number of columns or the location of the label '**name**'. So i can't use this answer, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: Reading 0 rows also works and is faster, although very marginally.

Comment: For anyone trying to optimize, just see [the answer from jalopezp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70892110/2738164) - no unnecessary reads of the file or awkward parsing, just using the built-in parameters of the read itself.

Answer (score 42):

The only parameter to `read_csv()` that you can use to select the columns you use is `usecols`. According to the documentation, `usecols` accepts list-like or callable. Because you only know the columns you want to drop, you can't use a list of the columns you want to keep. So use a callable:

```
pd.read_csv("sample.csv", usecols=lambda x: x != "name")
```

And you could of course say `x not in ["unwanted", "column", "names"]` if you had a list of column names you didn't want to use.

Comment: This is way much more clean than the accepted option

Comment: Pretty cool solution!

Answer (score 13):

Get the column headers from your CSV using `pd.read_csv` with `nrows=1`, then do a subsequent read with `usecols` to pull everything but the column(s) you want to omit.

```
headers = [*pd.read_csv('sample.csv', nrows=1)]
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols=[c for c in headers if c != 'name']))
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing (read only the headers) **very efficiently** using the CSV module,

```
import csv

with open("sample.csv", 'r') as f:
    header = next(csv.reader(f))
    # For python 2, use
    # header = csv.reader(f).next()

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols=list(set(header) - {'name'}))
```

Comment: This works fine. Is there a way to do it without importing 'csv' package? I mean, only using pandas.

Comment: @AnonGeorge You could use `pd.read_csv(..., nrows=1)` and then examine the headers. Leaving that as an exercise to you :)

Comment: `header = csv.reader(f).next()` will not work in python 3, i have edited your answer to correct it, but got rejected. :(

Answer (score 7):

Using `df= df.drop(['ID','prediction'],axis=1)` made the work for me. I dropped 'ID' and 'prediction' columns. Make sure you put them in square brackets like `['column1','column2']`.
There is no need for other complicated solutions.

Comment: This works, instead of copying to df again though you could just add an arg inplace=True e.g. df.drop(['ID','prediction'],axis=1, inplace=True). Which will apply the change on df directly.

Comment: OP already stated they know how to use `drop`, so not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Columns can be dropped at the time of reading itself.

```
columns_to_be_removed = ['a', 'b']

data = pd.read_csv(sourceFileName).drop(columns_to_be_removed, axis = 'columns')
```

Comment: Your solution is just chaining operations. The column is still read in the `read_csv` call.

Answer (score 1):

This answer with two lines of code will really help you. You can even dynamically remove column names while creating CSV.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71440977/12819393